# How to use dependencies from S3 in Zeppelin?

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-zeppelin

Is there a way to add jars that are in a bucket on S3 as a dependency of Zeppelin? tried `z.load(s3n://...)` and `z.addRepo(some_name).url(s3n://...)` but they don't seem to do the job..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could download jars from S3 and put it on the local FS. It could be done inside *%dep* interpreter like this:

```scala
%dep
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client
import java.io.File
import java.nio.file.{Files, StandardCopyOption}

val dest = "/tmp/dependency.jar"
val s3 = new AmazonS3Client()
val stream = s3.getObject("buckename", "path.jar").getObjectContent

Files.copy(stream, new File(dest).toPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING)

z.load(dest)
```

*Note:* You must generate fat jar, i.e. include all custom dependencies not provided by default (for example when you have multiple modules in your project). In maven it could be implemented with maven-shade-plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactSet>
                    <includes>
                        <include>com.yourcompany:*</include>
                    </includes>
                </artifactSet>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there a way you could also answer this question? thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37251236/apache-zeppelin-running-code-automatically-on-startup

Comment: I don't think think this works anymore. "DepInterpreter(%dep) deprecated. Load dependency through GUI interpreter menu instead."

Comment: I got this to work by following the instructions to upload the jar to the local file system.. and then going in to the interpreter menu and adding the dependency with the same path "/tmp/dependency.jar"

Comment: zeppelin also has a weird bug in 0.6.1. In order to pick up a NEW version of the jar (Even if you overwrote it with an update), you have to go in to the interpreter menu, edit the dependency field and click save (Which will restart the interpreter). You can't just restart the interpreter.