# Apache Zeppelin: Running code automatically on startup?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36769539/how-to-use-dependencies-from-s3-in-zeppelin/) explains how to add dependencies to Zeppelin from S3. Now I would like to run this code automatically whenever I launch Zeppelin. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. It can be done using the Zeppelin API:
https://zeppelin.incubator.apache.org/docs/0.5.6-incubating/rest-api/rest-notebook.html

Comment: how is it helpful in this case? (I'm also looking for a solution)

Comment: I use it in a script (Chef in my case) that launches Zeppelin and then executes `curl` commands which creates and runs the code